# python parse string to get contents between text

Tags: python, parsing

How can i collect the text (data) between a set of strings? For example I have this code snippet below, which is a modified version of json, which I don't have the ability to change.

However I want to collect the data between `presets = {...}`

```
{
    data = {
        friends = {
            max = 0 0,
            min = 0 0,
        },
        family = {
            cars = {
                van = "honda",
                car = "ford",
                bike = "trek",
            },
            presets = {
                location = "italy",
                size = 10,
                travelers = False,
            },
            version = 1,
        },
    },
}
```

So my resulting string would be whatever is between the two brackets `{...}` following the word presets. In this case it would be:

```
location = "italy",
size = 10,
travelers = False,
```

My starting point so far...

```
filepath = "C:/Users/jmartini/Projects/assets/tool_source.cfg"

with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')

    print data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PyYaml](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) to get the required data

> pip install PyYaml

```
import yaml
def testjson():
    with open('data.json') as datafile:
        data = datafile.read().replace("\n", "").replace("=", ":")            
        print(yaml.load(data)["data"]["family"]["presets"])
```

I get this output with your data

```
{'location': 'italy', 'size': 10, 'travelers': False}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` here.

```
import re
filepath = r"C:/Users/jmartini/Projects/rogue_presetsManager/assets/tool_leveleditormodule_source.cfg"
f=open(filepath, "r")
data = f.read()
print re.findall(r"presets\s*=\s*\{\s*([^}]*?)\s*}", data)
```

Comment: why do you do a double 'print'